# Query for resources using their URIs

Tags: sparql, rdf

I have a bunch of resource URIs, and I need the property values related to each of them.  For a single resource, say `<http://my.url/res#resourceUri>`, I can write this query:

```sql
PREFIX v: <http://my.url/res#>
SELECT ?name
WHERE {
    <http://my.url/res#resourceUri> a v:t;
        rdfs:label ?name .
}
```

For multiple resources, I can use **`UNION`**, like this:

```sql
PREFIX v: <http://my.url/res#>
SELECT ?name
WHERE {
    { <http://my.url/res#resourceUri> a v:t; rdfs:label ?name } UNION
    { <http://my.url/res#anotherResource> a v:t; rdfs:label ?name }
}
```

**Is there a way to write a shorter, leaner version of this second query?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [**values**](https://www.w3.org/TR/sparql11-query/#inline-data) for this.  Your example would be written as

```sql
PREFIX v: <http://my.url/res#>

SELECT ?resource ?name WHERE {
  values ?resource { <http://my.url/res#resourceUri>
                     <http://my.url/res#anotherResource> }
  ?resource a v:t;
            rdfs:label ?name
}
```

The question is different, but the answer to [how to use Union/or in sparql path with arbitrary length?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29233652/1281433) is similar.